# Graph does not show after type lattice command

Tags: r, graph, lattice

I installed the package `lattice`, and typed `xyplot()`. There is no error message but neither does a graph show up. I tried to switch to `plot()` and it works well. Any idea why it happened? Thank you!

Comment: it may also be that if you use R in batch mode, then you need to explicitly print() the lattice object for it to appear.

Comment: FAQ 7.22?: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require(lattice)
require(stats)

Depth <- equal.count(quakes$depth, number=8, overlap=.1)
my_plot <- xyplot(lat ~ long | Depth, data = quakes)
print(my_plot)
```

Thanks to richiemorrisroe and Gavin Simpson.