# lattice plots not working inside a function

Tags: r, printing, lattice

I have this R code, which works perfectly and i get the bitmap with the plot if i run it in R console or as a RScript

```
library(DBI);
library(RMySQL);
library(brew);
library(lattice);
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),server credentials)
x <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT name, distance FROM distances")
bitmap("/tmp/dist_6078.bmp")
dotplot(x$distance~x$name, col='red', xlab='name', ylab='distance', main='Distance plot')
dev.off()
```

Issue is, i am getting a blank image if i enclose everything between <% and %> and use brew library. Everything works fine if i use basic R plots, issue is only when i use lattice.

Comment: Have you tried saving the plot in a variable, `p` and then printing it, `print(p)`?

Comment: [R FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f) and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5450257/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6783120/

Comment: Yes, it works after adding print(). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the R FAQ 7.22

> Lattice functions such as xyplot() create a graph object, but do not
>   display it (the same is true of ggplot2 graphics, and Trellis graphics
>   in S-Plus). The print() method for the graph object produces the
>   actual display

Working code

```
library(DBI);
library(RMySQL);
library(brew);
library(lattice);
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),server credentials)
x <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT name, distance FROM distances")
bitmap("/tmp/dist_6078.bmp")
plot_obj <- dotplot(x$distance~x$name, col='red', xlab='name', ylab='distance', main='Distance plot')
print(plot_obj)
dev.off()
```