# Histogram from package lattice in a jpeg

Tags: r, jpeg, histogram, lattice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate multiple graphics from within an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547306/generate-multiple-graphics-from-within-an-r-function)

I'm trying to store all the plot from all the variables in my data with histogram from the package lattice.
When I run directly, it works but if I use a function don't create the figures.
My function is:

```
plotHistByGroups<-function(data, res)
{
   jpeg("plots/histBy%03d.jpg", quality=100)
   finalres<-as.factor(res)
   names<-colnames(data)
   library(lattice)
   for( i in 1: length(data))
   {
     title<-paste(names[i], "~")
     title<-paste(title, length(levels(finalres)))
     title<-paste(title, "clusters")
     histogram(~data[,i] | finalres, data, xlab=names[i], main=title)    
   }
   dev.off()
}
```

When I call the function, I only get one empty figure. But, I obtain all the figures If I directly run:

```
jpeg("plots/histBy%03d.jpg", quality=100)
histogram(~data[,1] | finalres, data, xlab=names[1], main=title)    
histogram(~data[,2] | finalres, data, xlab=names[2], main=title)    
histogram(~data[,3] | finalres, data, xlab=names[3], main=title)    
...
dev.off()
```

Bea

Comment: PS are you sure you want to save as JPEG?  Vector formats are best if possible, but even if you need a bitmap format, PNG is usually best for data graphics (JPEG is intended for photos and other pictures with gradual gradation in color)

Comment: I've never had problems with high res PNG's being of too low quality. All journals have accepted my PNG's without any problem.

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981507/lattice-plots-not-working-inside-a-function), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450257/graph-does-not-show-after-type-lattice-command) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783120/r-package-lattice-wont-plot-if-run-using-source).

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap this in a `print(histogram(...))` and yes, this is [question 7.22 in the R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f):

> 7.22 Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?
>
> The most likely reason is that you forgot to tell R to display the
>   graph. Lattice functions such as xyplot() create a graph object, but
>   do not display it (the same is true of ggplot2 graphics, and Trellis
>   graphics in S-PLUS). The print() method for the graph object produces
>   the actual display. When you use these functions interactively at the
>   command line, the result is automatically printed, but in source() or
>   inside your own functions you will need an explicit print() statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811106/cant-print-to-pdf-ggplot-charts , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541145/r-lattice-plots-and-postscript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188375/why-is-ggplot-not-plotting-multiple-windows-in-r , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547306/generate-multiple-graphics-from-within-an-r-function ...